# Show Barcode images in single page based on input number change by user using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, append, barcode

I am trying to show the barcode images when the user input the image number in `input` box. I am trying to do this using jquery `onchange` event and after that trying to do using `for` loop. It's returning the images, but inputted number and showed images not equal. It's reload again and again.Would someone please help me to correct the `loop` or what should be the correct approach? -

**index.html** --

```
<input type="number" name="counter" value="10" id="counter" onchange="getBarcode()">

<div class="row barcodeimages" id="barcodeimages">

</div>
```

And my **script** is -

```
 getBarcode();
 function getBarcode() {
    let num = 0;
    let counter = $("#counter").val();
    for (num = 0; num <= counter - 1; num++) {
              $(".barcodeimages").append(`<div class="col-xs-3">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/16/19/barcode-306926__340.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
               </div>`);
    }
 }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashed50702/mukhLfgz/24/)

Comment: I dont know if I understand your question. Would this help? https://jsfiddle.net/6bnsv35m/